# finding non-identical entries across a row

Tags: r

I have a 2380 rows data.frame that looks like this:

```
>   nstudentid1 nstudentid2 nstudentid3
1    80501010    80501010    80501010
2    80501022    80501022    80501022
3    80501005    80501005    80501005
4    80501003    80501003    80501003
5    80501026    80501026    80501026
6    80501025    80501025    80501025
```

As you can see the variables are subject ID's.
Each subject got three ID's for cross-validation.

Usually we want to find duplicated entries within a coulmn, which I already did.

Now I would like to check if each subject (row) has exactley the same ID number across all three ID variables.

I ran a general check:

```
all(student1$nstudentid1 == student1$nstudentid2)
all(student1$nstudentid1 == student1$nstudentid3)
all(student1$nstudentid2 == student1$nstudentid3)
```

and got FALSE as an answer.

How do i find the non-identical row numbers?

Any advice will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your condition as filter :

```
condition <- student1$nstudentid1 == student1$nstudentid2 &
             student1$nstudentid1 == student1$nstudentid3 &
             student1$nstudentid2 == student1$nstudentid3;

nonIdenticalRows <- student1[!condition,]
```

To get just the row numbers do :

```
rowNumbers <- which(!condition)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot great and understandable answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
 indx <- rowSums(student1==student1[,1])!=ncol(student1)

 student1[indx,]
```

To get row numbers,

```
  which(indx)          
  #  named integer(0) #none of the rows meet the condition
```

In your example, the columns are identical, So, if I change:

```
  student1[3,3] <- 804015
  indx <- rowSums(student1==student1[,1])!=ncol(student1)
  student1[indx,]
  #nstudentid1 nstudentid2 nstudentid3
  #3    80501005    80501005      804015
```

#### Explanation

- `student1==student1[,1]` It is checking whether the dataset is equal to the first column.  Basically, what it is doing is we are checking whether te first column is equal to each of the columns of the dataset.  Output we get is:

  ```
    nstudentid1 nstudentid2 nstudentid3
  1        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  2        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  3        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  4        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  5        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  6        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  ```
- Suppose, if I change one of the elements. `student1[3,3] <- 804015`, the output would be:

  ```
    nstudentid1 nstudentid2 nstudentid3
  1        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  2        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  3        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE
  4        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  5        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  6        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
  ```
- Doing `rowSums(student1==student1[,1])` gives

  ```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 
    3 3 2 3 3 3
  ```
- here, the third row/element has less number of identical entries.  Equating that to number of columns of dataset. `rowSums(student1==student1[,1])!=ncol(student1)` gives

  ```
         1     2     3     4     5     6 
      FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ```

Also, you could try:

```
  indx1 <- unique(which(student1!=student1[,1],arr.ind=TRUE)[,1])
  student1[indx1,]
  #nstudentid1 nstudentid2 nstudentid3
  #3    80501005    80501005      804015
```

Comment: Came back: integer(0). It's way above my level to understand your command so i don't know why it happend. anyway thanks for helping out

Comment: @user3821211. As I mentioned in the post, your columns as showed in the example were all identical.  I changed one of the elements and got the result as showed.  Also, if you have many columns, this approach would be easier to use.